# android canvas drawBitMap and switch between images on certain interval

Tags: android, canvas, android-animation, surfaceview, ondraw

Application's camera activity using surfaceview and bitmap is drawn (**white rectangles**) using **canvas.drawBitMap()** method inside on **onDraw()** method of surfaceview.
I used following code to achieve this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_top_left), x1, y1, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_top_right), x2, y1, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_bottom_left), x1, y2, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_bottom_right), x2, y2, null);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

But I want an animation effect by switching between 2 bitmaps, which should look something as shown below:

[image]

I tried to find out few solution (even on stackoverflow) but found only lengthy and costly. Please suggest some clean and less costly approach.

**All this I am doing inside surfaceview using canvas.**

Answer (score 0):

I did it by calling on postInvalidateDelayed in **onDraw()** of the surfaceview.

```
postInvalidateDelayed(500, left,top,right,bottom);
```

This is how it works, **onDraw()** method is called every 500 milli seconds that time change the bitmap (red if it is white and white if it is red). Changing between image can be done using simple flag.

```
    if(rectBlink){
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_top_left_white), x1, y1, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_top_right_white), x2, y1, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_bottom_left_white), x1, y2, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_bottom_right_white), x2, y2, null);
        }
        else{
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_top_left_red), x1, y1, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_top_right_red), x2, y1, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_bottom_left_red), x1, y2, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.corner_bottom_right_red), x2, y2, null);
        }
```

And then change the flag status form true to false or false to true using code below:

```
rectBlink=!rectBlink;
```

This is all done.